# handle chrome alerts through UFT

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, qtp

I am trying to handle chrome alerts through UFT(Unified Funtional Testing)/QTP(Quick Test Professional). There are only a few options such as Insight objects, sendkeys or by coordinate values. I need more robust way to handle these alerts. Like how the selenium does with help of webdriver. 
Is there any other way to handle alerts externally such that those methods can be triggered through a .vbs file?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

UFT has the [`Browser.HandleDialog`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~Browser.html#HandleDialog) functionality which allows clicking **OK** on `alert` and `confirm` dialogs, clicking **Cancel** on `confirm` and `prompt` dialogs and entering values for `prompt` dialogs.

Usage:

```
Browser("B").HandleDialog micOK

Browser("B").HandleDialog micCancel

Browser("B").HandleDialog micOK, "value for prompt dialog"
```

Comment: During recording, I click the ok button and I get this code Browser("Create New record").HandleDialog micOK. During run time I get this error "This operation can not be performed". Please advise.

Comment: @bugfinder, this sounds like a bug, have you tried contacting UFT's support?

Comment: I did and they said "UFT can not handle JS alerts or dialog boxes, so it is an expected behavior". Insight object works but it may not work other machines. I am stuck. Any other workaround?

Comment: @bugfinder which version of UFT are you using?

Comment: 14.00/Build 1775

Comment: I will look up the person. Thanks.